# When are these dense subspaces of the torus homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

We define the torus $T^2$ as the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the relation $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ if $a-c,b-d \in \mathbb{Z}$, with the quotient map $q : \mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$.  Let $\theta$ be an irrational real number. We can define the injective function $f_\theta : \mathbb{R} \to T^2$ by $f_\theta(x) = q(x,\theta x)$. Let $X_\theta$ be the subspace whose underlying set is the image of $f_\theta$. Let $\sigma$ be another irrational number. When are $X_\theta$ and $X_\sigma$ homeomorphic?

These subspaces are all dense in $T^2$, and they are all locally homeomorphic. There are obvious homeomorphisms: $$X_\theta \cong X_{-\theta} \cong X_{1/\theta} \cong X_{-1/\theta}.$$
We also have
$$ X_\theta \cong X_{\theta + m}$$
for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I got interested in these topologies because they are simple examples of spaces such that applying the [locally path-connected coreflection functor](https://wildtopology.com/2014/10/11/the-locally-path-connected-coreflection/) gives a space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean topology. Notably, for any continuous function $h : X_\theta \to X_\sigma$, we have that $f^{-1}_\sigma \circ h \circ f_\theta : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Therefore, if there is an homeomorphism $h : X_\theta \to X_\sigma$, there is an homeomorphism $h' : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $h = f_\sigma \circ h' \circ f^{-1}_\theta$.  Hence, we want to find an homeomorphism $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_\sigma \circ h' \circ f^{-1}_\theta$ and $f_\theta \circ h' \circ f^{-1}_\sigma$ are continuous. Because $X_\theta$ and $X_\sigma$ are metrizable spaces, we know that a map between them is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous. So $X_\theta$ and $X_\sigma$ are homeomorphic if and only if we can find a homeomorphism $h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for any sequence of reals $(r_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, any real number $r$, we have that $(r_i - r)$ and $(\theta r_i - \theta r)$ converges to $0$ $\mathrm{mod} \: 1$ if and only if $(h(r_i) - h(r))$ and $(\sigma h(r_i) - \sigma h(r))$ converges to $0$ $\mathrm{mod} \: 1$. But then I'm stuck.

Comment: You can generalize your examples by noting that for any $M \in GL(2,\mathbb Z)$ acting by [fractional linear transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation) on $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, $X_\theta \cong X_{M(\theta)}$. All that's going on here is that $GL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is generated by the three transformations $\theta \mapsto -\theta$, $\theta \mapsto 1/\theta$, $\theta \mapsto \theta + 1$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher that's a nice way to describe it indeed!

Comment: Knowing the theorem which says that the tail of the continued fraction expansion of $\theta$ is a complete invariant of its $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ orbit, this leads me to wonder whether the two tails of the two continued fraction expansions of $\theta$ and $-\theta$, can be determined solely from the topology of $X_\theta$.